Induced map of degree $k$ self map of a sphere in the higher homotopy groups
Let $f:S^n\rightarrow S^n$ be a degree $k$ map. Then $f$ induces maps $\pi_l(S^n)\rightarrow \pi_l(S^n)$.
I believe that in the stable range ($l\leq 2n-2$) this map is multiplication by $k$. Unstably this need not be the case. Pontryagin proved the induced map $\pi_3(S^2)\rightarrow \pi_3(S^2)$ is multiplication by $k^2$.
I am not known as a stable mathematician and therefore I wonder: is it known what happens unstably in general?
I understand that we are very far from computing the unstable homotopy groups of spheres, but one might still know what the induced maps are without knowing the groups themselves.

See my answer here. The method works in higher dimensions up to knowing certain Whitehead products and Hopf invariants. This doesn't quite answer your question, though.

What I can add is that an odd-dimensional sphere localised at an odd prime is an H-space. Thus for an odd-dimensional sphere, the degree $k$ map acts as multiplication by $k$ on odd primary components. The 2-primary case is not completely understood.

Dear Tyrone, thank you for your excellent answer, I didn't see that question before. This tells me how to think about these maps. Of course this involves many computations for all unstable groups. This is more complicated than that I hoped for, but I guess that was to be expected. Again, thanks for the pointers!
